# How to solve this Psycopg error message (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I recently modified my insert query and started receiving this error message:

```
error: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead
```

Here is the SQL insert string, which caused this error:

```
timestamp = 'NOW()::timestamp'

sql_insert_command = 
"INSERT INTO test_table(
article_id, 
date_published, 
date_modified, 
row_created_on, 
row_modified_on )" 
"VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
(new_record[0],new_record[1],new_record[2],timestamp,timestamp)
```

This is the SQL string that is getting passed to my query function:

```
('INSERT INTO test_table(
article_id, 
date_published, 
date_modified, 
row_created_on, 
row_modified_on)
VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', 
('0530973', 
'2018-01-10 17:29:00', 
'2018-02-15 11:58:32', 
'NOW()::timestamp', 
'NOW()::timestamp'))
```

---

This is my old string, which works, but violates the NEVER do statement here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

```
sql_insert_command = 
"INSERT INTO test_table(
article_id, 
date_published, 
date_modified, 
row_created_on, 
row_modified_on ) " \
"VALUES('" + new_record[0] + "','" + 
new_record[1]+ "','" + 
new_record[2] + "'," + 
timestamp + "," + 
timestamp + ")"
```

This is the SQL string that is getting passed to my query function with the command above:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(article_id, 
date_published, 
date_modified,
row_created_on, 
row_modified_on)
VALUES('0530973',
'2018-01-10 17:29:00',
'2018-02-15 11:58:32',
NOW()::timestamp,
NOW()::timestamp)
```

What is causing this error message? And how do I solve this issue?

Here's is the code that I'm using to connect to the database and insert a record:

```
class DatabaseConnection(object):

_instance = None

def __new__(cls):
    if cls._instance is None:
        cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)

        db_config = {'dbname': 'development', 'host': 'localhost',
                 'password': 'somepassword', 'port': 5432, 'user': 'postgres'}
        try:
            print('connecting to PostgreSQL database...')
            connection = DatabaseConnection._instance.connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_config)
            connection.autocommit = True
            cursor = DatabaseConnection._instance.cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT VERSION()')
            db_version = cursor.fetchone()

        except Exception as error:
            print('Error: connection not established {}'.format(error))
            DatabaseConnection._instance = None

        else:
            print('connection established\n{}'.format(db_version[0]))

    return cls._instance

def __init__(self):
    self.connection = self._instance.connection
    self.cursor = self._instance.cursor

def insert_new_records(self, insert_query):
    try:
        # used for testing
        print (insert_query)

        result = self.cursor.execute(insert_query)

    except Exception as error:
        print('error execting query "{}", error: {}'.format(insert_query, error))
        return None
    else:
        return result

def __del__(self):
    self.connection.close()
    self.cursor.close()
```

Code that I'm using to insert a record:

```
new_record = ("0530973", "2018-01-10 17:29:00", "2018-02-15 11:58:32",
              "0530974", "2018-01-10 17:29:00", "2018-02-15 11:58:32")


timestamp = 'NOW()::timestamp'

sql_insert_command = 
"INSERT INTO test_table(
article_id, 
date_published, 
date_modified, 
row_created_on, 
row_modified_on ) " \
"VALUES('" + new_record[0] + "','" + 
new_record[1]+ "','" + 
new_record[2] + "'," + 
timestamp + "," + 
timestamp + ")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `timestamp` when interpreted by `execute` is incorrectly enclosed in single quotes.

The simplest way is to use just strings instead of the variable in the sql text:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO test_table(
    article_id, 
    date_published, 
    date_modified, 
    row_created_on, 
    row_modified_on )
    VALUES(%s,%s,%s,now()::timestamp,now()::timestamp)""",
    (new_record[0],new_record[1],new_record[2])
    )
```

More elegant solution with `format()`:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO test_table(
    article_id, 
    date_published, 
    date_modified, 
    row_created_on, 
    row_modified_on )
    VALUES(%s,%s,%s,{},{})""".format(timestamp,timestamp),
    (new_record[0],new_record[1],new_record[2])
    )
```

You can also use the function `AsIs()` from extensions:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO test_table(
    article_id, 
    date_published, 
    date_modified, 
    row_created_on, 
    row_modified_on )
    VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
    (new_record[0],new_record[1],new_record[2],AsIs(timestamp),AsIs(timestamp))
    )
```

Comment: I tried all 3 examples, but still get this: error execting error: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead

Comment: Then you have an extra problem with `new_record`. Edit the question and show precisely what it is. It should be a simple list of strings: `['0530973', '2018-01-10 17:29:00', '2018-02-15 11:58:32']`

Comment: the question has been updated

Comment: I see, there is a misunderstanding, see the updated answer.

Comment: The "update" is covered by the "NEVER DO" part in the docs. It's bad form teaching string formatting/concatenation as a solution. The original attempt fails exactly for the reason described in the error: `sql_insert_command` is a tuple of sql string, args; it is not a string. A solution would be to just unpack it as args to `execute()`, though usually this situation is a result of a misunderstanding and the solutions you first offered would be the proper answer.

Comment: Are you saying that I should be passing my data to execute() in this way? 
db.insert_new_records(sql_insert_command, data)

Comment: Well, you should modify the method so it can accept two arguments. And yes, the solution in *Update* would work but is not a good practice (so I'll remove it for future readers).

Comment: Hopefully, this is correct:    data = (new_record[0],new_record[1],new_record[2]) db.insert_new_records(sql_insert_command, data)

Comment: THANKS for the assistance!!